# Make_bricks from codingbat

Tags: python

I'm new and looking for a hint in make_bricks from codingbat (see [here](https://codingbat.com/prob/p118406)). I wrote some code, but not everything works properly. Maybe someone could give me a hint?

---

**TASK**

We want to make a row of bricks that is goal inches long. We have a number of small bricks (1 inch each) and big bricks (5 inches each). Return `True` if it is possible to make the goal by choosing from the given bricks. This is a little harder than it looks and can be done without any loops.

---

**Bug**

I have a problem with:

- `make_bricks(3, 1, 9) → False`  - my code is `True`
- `make_bricks(3, 2, 9) → False` - my code is `True`
- `make_bricks(1, 4, 12) → False` - my code is `True`

---

**My code:**

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
    return small==goal or big==goal or goal%5==small or small*1+big*5==goal or 
    goal%5<=small or small+big!=goal or goal-5!=small or goal-small*1==big*5
```

[make_bricks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoBKI.png)

Comment: Please review people's replies - if any of these is helpful, you could upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

When you arrive at outcomes that are incorrect or are other than you might expect, it's often helpful to break down the steps to identify where things may have gone wrong. For example, here is your code broken down slightly differently so you can follow the logical flow a bit more easily.

```py
# ======================================
# Your code written slightly differently
# ======================================

def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
    if small==goal:
        return 1
    elif big==goal:
        return 2
    elif goal%5==small:
        return 3
    elif small*1+big*5==goal:
        return 4
    elif goal%5<=small:
        return 5
    elif small+big!=goal:
        return 6
    elif goal-5!=small:
        return 7
    elif goal-small*1==big*5:
        return 8
    else:
        return False
        
print(make_bricks(3, 1, 9))
print(make_bricks(3, 2, 9))
print(make_bricks(1, 4, 12))
```

This gives you a hint as to how you might identify which evaluation may not be working quite the way you expect. Before revealing the explanation, see if you can identify the culprit.

> Evaluation #6 of your code returns `True` when  `small + big does not equal the goal`.  Because the result of this evaluation is `True` (it does not equal the goal), your script is returning `True`.  In fact, your code will return `True` for every combination you test.
>
>  In order to get to the results you expect, you'll need to correct the offending evaluation and refactor your code a bit to account for the `False` condition.

Once you have the code working the way you would like, you can always consolidate operations or otherwise refactor to make the code more lean and efficient.

Comment: Just to add insight to my answer, my goal was not to solve the problem for the OP, but to provide a ***hint***--which is what the OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved rather simply like this:

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
    rem = goal - 5 * min( (goal//5), big )
    if rem > small:
        return False
    return True
```

The expression `min( (goal//5), big )` calculates how many of the provided big bricks that will fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code :

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
    return small==goal or big==goal or goal%5==small or small*1+big*5==goal or 
    goal%5<=small or  goal-small*1==big*5
```

this code return :

`make_bricks(3, 1, 9) → False`

`make_bricks(3, 2, 9) → False`

`make_bricks(1, 4, 12) → False`

but if use:
`goal-5!=small` for goal=9,small=3 :

```
print(9-5!=3) ---> True
```

`or`  Returns True if one of the statements is true